# How and when to get user's input from address bar in BHO

Tags: internet-explorer, bho, dispatchevent

I'm writing a BHO for IE. I want to get user's input from address bar. The input can be a url or search key word.
Beacuse there are other BHOs will change the user's input as a eligible url. I don't need the change and want to get the raw input from user.
Which dispatch event will be the suitable  time to get the raw input from user in BHO?  How can I to get it?
Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to ensure that your BHO is the first to get the message.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 I see a window (using Spy++) with class "Address Band Root". This is presumably the address bar in the browser. It has a child window which is an edit control. You could subclass or hook this edit control so you get the `EN_CHANGE` or `EN_UPDATE` notifications. Then you could query it for the current text. This is a pretty advanced technique but it is often the case that doing simple things in IE requires complex code.

Oh, and I should mention that this presumably won't work in IE protected mode. You could implement a separate COM object and have the BHO instantiate it and have it do the dirty work. Normally IE will prompt the user for permission to access the elevated mode process, but you can use the registry to [override this behaviour](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918239/en-us?spid=8722&sid=global).

Like I said, this is advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at BeforeNavigate2 event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have red it. But the input I get in BeforeNavigate2 event may be not the raw input from user. The input may be edited by other BHOs. e.g. if user's input is "baby", we just want to get "baby", not a edited input as url "www.baby.com".